# Are other users' private databases accessible via CKRecordZoneID.ownerName?

Tags: ios, cloudkit

[Conventional wisdom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31350136/cloudkit-share-private-container-between-users) is that, if a CloudKit record is in a private database, it can only be accessed by that user.

However, I've found an API in the frameworks that I don't understand. `CKRecordZoneID`'s initializer takes two parameters:

> `zoneName`: The name that identifies the record zone. The string must contain only ASCII characters and must not exceed 255 characters. To specify the default zone of the current database, pass the `CKRecordZoneDefaultName` constant for this parameter. This parameter must not be `nil` or the empty string.
>
> `ownerName`: The user who created the record zone. To specify the current user, use the `CKOwnerDefaultName` constant. If you specify `nil` or an empty string for this parameter, this method throws an exception.

What I don't understand is what the `ownerName` parameter is for. Zones aren't available in public databases, so it must be used for private ones. But to what end?

There are a couple other curious statements in the docs. From `CKRecordZoneID`'s introduction:

> ...zones in a private database can only be *created* by the user that owns the database.

From `CKContainer`:

> ...the contents of the private database are visible only to the current user *by default*.

All this gives me a sneaking suspicion that, if you got your hands on the user and zone names for an existing zone in another user's private database, you could construct a `CKRecordZoneID` and access it.

Is this the case? Has anyone tried it? If it doesn't work, what is the purpose of the `ownerName`?

Answer (score 1):

When **creating a record zone** (only possible in the private database), you can only use the creator’s user record name as the `ownerName`, or better `CKCurrentUserDefaultName` (`CKOwnerDefaultName` is deprecated) because the creator, i.e. the current user, IS the owner.

When **querying / subscribing to changes** in the **shared database**, a record zone can have its owner different than the current user. So you can initialize a record zone ID by specifying its zone name and owner name, and then use the record zone ID to perform querying / subscribing.

I haven’t tried sharing using CloudKit yet, please correct me if my understanding is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I think the purpose of this 'subcategory' is so that a specific user can create multiple zones within their private database by differentiating each zone with a simple text string that the documents refer to as "ownerName".  That seems to be what the sample code is doing here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/CloudAtlas/Listings/iOS_CloudKitCatalog_AAPLCKRecordViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014599-iOS_CloudKitCatalog_AAPLCKRecordViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_26

Comment: This sample app doesn't create any zones with custom owners. The only custom zones it creates are with `[[CKRecordZone alloc] initWithZoneName:self.zoneTextField.text]`, which doesn't include the `ownerName:` parameter.